# Does autoionization occur in steam?

Tags: water, phase

It is well known that H<sub>2</sub>O spontaneously autoionizes to H<sup>+</sup> and OH<sup>-</sup> when it is in liquid phase. I was wondering whether it does the same in gas phase, either to the same extent as in liquid phase or at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, water is ionized to some extent in all phases. [One study](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j100221a013) even extends to 1,000 K!

A [concise discussion of the change in ionization with temperature at Chemguide](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/acidbaseeqia/kw.html) also explains the variation of pH of neutral water with temperature. [The concept of pH 7 being neutral is based on Kw (in mol<sup>2</sup> dm<sup>-6</sup>) of ~10<sup>-14</sup> at ~300 K.]

In general, the higher the temperature, the more a compound is ionized.

Comment: Thing is, in actual vapour and low temp. auto-ionisation is as good as non-existent.

Comment: @Mithoron, read the answer: "water is ionized to **some extent**". "as good as non-existent," is not *none*.

Comment: OP asked to what extent. Later you talk about liquid water. While it's true that raising temp. raised deg. of autoionization, vaporisation lowers it extremely.